# Htaccess redirect 301 add element before id url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect my domain with format:

```
example.com/abc-def/product-name-123.html
```

to

```
example.com/product-name-p123.html (add element P before id)
```

I am trying but it isn't working.

Comment: You should include what you have tried in your question. Also, do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? As the order of directives is importantant.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[\w-]+/([\w-]+)-(\d+\.html)$ /$1-p$2 [R,L]
```

This assumes the subdirectory "abc-def" is variable and contains just the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` or `-`. However, if this should literally be `/abc-def` then include that here instead.

This also assumes that "product-name" only consists of the characters: `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` or `-`.

This is a temporary (302) redirect. Only change it to a 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK, to avoid browser caching issues.

Comment: I understood, I corrected it

RewriteRule ^abc-def/([a-z0-9-]+)-(\d+\.html)$ /$1-p$2 [R=301,L]

And it worked, thanks a lot

Comment: Your "correction" is really no different? - it is just more restrictive. (The regex in my answer would have still matched your example URL - as it is more generic) Was that the problem - was it matching too much before? Otherwise, you may have been seeing a cached response... if you had previously tested erroneous 301 redirects then these "errors" will have been cached by the browser. (?)

Comment: Yes, because it conflicts with other rule ^^

Comment: Glad you got it working, please mark the answer as "accepted" (checkmark below the voting arrows on the left) to remove the question from the unanswered question queue. Thanks, much appreciated :) Once you have 15+ rep you can also upvote answers you find useful.